# How could I let Xdebug steping over the code

Tags: php, laravel, xdebug

I have been working with Laravel version 7 with php7.4 and suddenly my Xdebug is not steping over the lines but before is working fine and I don't change or touch any configuration file.

vscode configuraion

```json
"version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9003,
            "stopOnEntry":false
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 9000
        }
    ]
```

php.ini

```
[XDEBUG]
xdebug.mode=debug
;my-updates
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.default_enable=1
xdebug.remote_port=9003
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
;end
zend_extension = C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-3.0.1-7.4-vc15-x86_64.dll
```

and extension

```
PHP Debug felixfbecker.php-debug v1.14.9
```

so when I set breakpoint on a line its cache but is not step over the lines also I set many breakpoints and press button debug called continue also is jump to this function

```php
    public function prepareResponse($request, $response)
    {
        return static::toResponse($request, $response);
    }
```

Comment: "Suddenly" sounds strange. What has changed?

Comment: I mean is working before, jsut is stop to step over @Nico Haase

Comment: You are using Xdebug v3 .. but have config parameters for Xdebug v2. They do almost nothing in v3. Check https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide first. https://learnxdebug.com/ + https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IN6ihpJSFDw